# python matplotlib yaxis shifting image

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am producing an image such as the following in Python3.6:

[image]

via the following code:

```
# What file are we reading in?
file2read0 = "/path0/" + yyyy + '_' + monthy + '.npy'
file2read1 = "/path1/" + yyyy + '_' + monthy + '.npy'
file2read2 = "/path2/" + yyyy + '_' + monthy + '.npy'
file2read3 = "/path3/" + yyyy + '_' + monthy + '.npy'
file2read4 = "/path4/" + yyyy + '_' + monthy + '.npy'

# Read the files!
data0 = np.load(file2read0,allow_pickle=True)
data1 = np.load(file2read1,allow_pickle=True)
data2 = np.load(file2read2,allow_pickle=True)
data3 = np.load(file2read3,allow_pickle=True)
data4 = np.load(file2read4,allow_pickle=True)

alldata = np.vstack([data0,data1])
alldata = np.vstack([alldata,data2])
alldata = np.vstack([alldata,data3])
alldata = np.vstack([alldata,data4])
alldata = alldata.astype(int)

fig,ax = plt.subplots()
im = ax.imshow(alldata)

ax.set_xticks(np.arange(len(dayy)))
ax.set_xticklabels(dayy)
plt.setp(ax.get_xticklabels(), rotation=45, ha="right", rotation_mode="anchor")

for i in range(0,5):
    for j in range(0,len(dayy)):
        text = ax.text(j,i,alldata[i,j], ha="center",va="center",color="w")
```

This code does a vast majority of what I want done. The problem now is I want to alter the text on the yaxis. I want each row to have a ytick, and have a label associated with it (let's just say path0, path2, ... , path4) via the following code (similar to above, just now with the yaxis):

```
ax.set_yticks(np.arange(5))
ax.set_yticklabels(["path0","path1","path2","path3","path4"])
plt.setp(ax.get_yticklabels(), rotation=45, ha="right", rotation_mode="anchor")
```

I get the following:

[image]

I would like to know why this is happening, and how to best remedy this so the bottom/top halves of the data are not chopped off with the added text?

Comment: Does it get any better when you use `ax.set_ylim(-0.5, 4.5)` after `ax.set_yticklabels(["path0","path1","path2","path3","path4"])`?

Comment: Always the easiest of answers. Thanks!